# Encontrar un valor respectivo en una lista

Tags: python, pycharm

Necesito que mi función halle de la lista el valor del diámetro 12.104 y al imprimirlo no me sale nada. Todavia le puse el *int* y no me sale nada. Además deseo ordenarlos por orden del número de diametro

```
mercurio = {"planeta": "mercurio ", "diametro": 4.878}
venus = {"planeta": "venus", "diametro": 12.104}
tierra = {"planeta": "tierra", "diametro": 12.756}
marte = {"planeta": "marte ", "diametro": 6.794}
jupiter = {"planeta": "jupiter", "diametro": 142.800}
saturno = {"planeta": "saturno", "diametro": 120.660}
urano = {"planeta": "urano", "diametro": 51.800}
neptuno = {"planeta": "neptuno", "diametro": 49.500}


lista = []
lista.append(mercurio)
lista.append(venus)
lista.append(tierra)
lista.append(marte)
lista.append(jupiter)
lista.append(urano)
lista.append(neptuno)


for Lista2 in lista:
    print(Lista2)


def busquedad(valor):
    for p in lista:
        if p["diametro"] == int(valor):
            print("El planeta con diametro igual a ", valor, " es ",p["planeta"])
            return p

valor = 12.104

busquedad(valor)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en usar `int()`, te cito un fragmento de lo que dice la [referencia en la documentación oficial de Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

> For floating point numbers, this truncates towards zero.

Traducción:

Para números decimales se cortará la parte decimal hacia 0.

**La demostración de esto:**

```
valor = 12.104

print(valor)
print(int(valor))
```

Devuelve el resultado

```
12.104
12
```

En resumen al usar `int()` estás redondeando el número decimal a un número entero, por eso mismo tu algoritmo no tiene concidencias.

Cambiando está linea de esta manera:

```
if i["diametro"] == valor: # Antes era 'if i["diametro"] == int(valor):'
```

Se solucionaría el problema.

**Otras observaciones que me gustaría hacerte:**

-La manera más eficiente de añadir múltiples elementos a una lista es con el método `.extend()`

En tu código original existe este fragmento:

```
lista = []
lista.append(mercurio)
lista.append(venus)
lista.append(tierra)
lista.append(marte)
lista.append(jupiter)
lista.append(urano)
lista.append(neptuno)
```

Se cumple exactamente el mismo objetivo en menos lineas de código con `.extends()`:

```
lista = []
lista.extend([mercurio,venus,tierra,marte,jupiter,urano,neptuno])
```

Hice unos cambios para que tu código se más legible (leer comentarios del código):

```
mercurio = {"planeta": "mercurio ", "diametro": 4.878}
venus = {"planeta": "venus", "diametro": 12.104}
tierra = {"planeta": "tierra", "diametro": 12.756}
marte = {"planeta": "marte ", "diametro": 6.794}
jupiter = {"planeta": "jupiter", "diametro": 142.800}
saturno = {"planeta": "saturno", "diametro": 120.660}
urano = {"planeta": "urano", "diametro": 51.800}
neptuno = {"planeta": "neptuno", "diametro": 49.500}


lista = []
lista.extend([mercurio,venus,tierra,marte,jupiter,urano,neptuno]) #Un mejor método de añadir elementos a la lista

for planeta in lista: #Un nomre a la variable temporal, más legible
    print(planeta)

def busqueda(valor):
    for i in lista:
        if i["diametro"] == valor: # Antes era 'if i["diametro"] == int(valor):'
            print(f"El planeta con diametro igual a {valor} es {i['planeta']}") #Una concatenación más eficiente

valor = 12.104
busqueda(valor)
```

Da como resultado:

```
{'planeta': 'mercurio ', 'diametro': 4.878}
{'planeta': 'venus', 'diametro': 12.104}
{'planeta': 'tierra', 'diametro': 12.756}
{'planeta': 'marte ', 'diametro': 6.794}
{'planeta': 'jupiter', 'diametro': 142.8}
{'planeta': 'urano', 'diametro': 51.8}
{'planeta': 'neptuno', 'diametro': 49.5}
El planeta con diametro igual a 12.104 es venus
```

Espero te haya servido, saludos!

Comment: De mucha ayuda. Una consulta como harias para ordenarlo de acuerdo al número de diametro sin usar sort() ?  Yo hice algo así: def ordenar(lista):
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        h = i
        while h > 0 and lista[h] < lista[h - 1]:
            aux = lista[h]
            lista[h] = lista[h - 1]
            lista[h - 1] = aux
            h = h - 1
            print(lista)